# Is there a better way of checking how activity was finished in onDestroy than setting a flag?

Tags: android, flags

I want to call foo() every time my activity is destroyed, unless it is destroyed as result of clicking on a specific menu option (that eventually calls finish()). Currently I do this by calling foo() on default in onDestroy, unless a FLAG is set to true, where FLAG is set when I intercept the click on the menu option.

Is there a better way of doing this than setting a flag? Perhaps some way I can attach a tag to Android's finish() so that I can see the reason? Normally I would just try to call foo where it applies, but I can't account for every reason an activity might be destroyed.

Further caveat is that I would prefer not to make changes to base class (RootActivity)

```
    public abstract class RootActivity extends Activity{
    private flag someCondition;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        //... 
    }
    // ...

    public void startJob(JobAction.Id jobaction){
        if (!jobaction.someCondition){
            return;
        }else{
            startSomeLongAsynchronousJob(someCondition);
            finish(); //If this is why onDestroy happened in subclass, I dont want to call foo()
        }

    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        //...
        startJob(JobAction.SOMEENUM);  //Startjob is being called in the superclass
    }
    //...
}


public class SpecificJob extends SomeClassThatExtendsRoot{
    private boolean FLAG = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        //...
    }
    // ... some code ...
    @Override
    public onDestroy(){
        if (!FLAG){    //Check if it was finish() that did this
            foo();
        }
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if (item.getItemId()==r.id.DONTCALLFOO){
            flag=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to override onSaveInstanceState in your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d("ApplicationFlow","onSaveInstanceState was called. System destroy your activity");

    foo();

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

It is always called when the activity is destroyed by the system, and not by you (when you call finish()).

The purpose is give to user a chance to save some state in `Bundle outState` parameter. This bundle will be passed to `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to the user restore the state, when the activity is going to be recreated.

[See documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: But I don't need to recreate it - so I don't ever retrieve the state from the bundle? onSaveInstanceState is used for saving state when the app needs to be closed by Android OS - not for calls like finish or pressing back. I'm not sure how that applies here.

Comment: I was thinking that you want to know when the app is closed either by OS or user. For this reason a writed this answer.

Comment: Oh, I am closing the app in both instances. In any case, I think I'll just go ahead with it using a flag; it appears I was put in this situation by how the rest of my project was designed. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: I can't get yet what do you want to know.  You want to know the reason for  the application called onDestroy?